# What are the good sources for Singapore Mathematics?

Tags: algebra, linear-algebra

I am looking for the conceptual/visualisation way of tackling the algebra problems . I found that Singapore Maths caters this need. What are the good sources for Singapore Maths - any online classes for Singapore Maths. My aim is to mentally solve any word problems - algebra so that I score high marks in the competitive exams like GRE. Also, This way I can crack the algebra problems visually rather than x, y and z.

Comment: To be clear: You are asking about curricular materials - especially those associated with "Singapore Math" - that use a conceptual/visual approach to help students become better solvers of GRE-level algebra word problems?

Comment: Previously asked at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/967934/18398 where it has been put on hold.  Before it was put on hold, I asked the OP to post it here because I felt the question was more on-topic here.

Comment: See my answer for http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/5806/free-websites-to-practice-math-for-the-common-core-standards on free websites to practice math

Comment: @JPBurke: That's just an American site trying to sell stuff.

Comment: Just to point out that if it were "authentic", it would be Singapore Math*s* (British spelling). Also, in Singapore, Maths is pronounced (mispronounced?) as "matz" (so quite different from either the American or British pronunciation).

Answer (score 6):

You asked about online classes for Singapore math. I realize you may no longer need this info, but thought someone browsing the questions might appreciate it.

I recommend the courses at [ed2go](http://ed2go.com)
There are two classes one for [1st-6th](http://www.ed2go.com/online-courses/singapore-math-strategies-model-drawing-for-grades-1-6?tab=detail) and one for [6th-9th](http://www.ed2go.com/online-courses/singapore-math-strategies-model-drawing-for-grades-6-9?tab=detail).
The courses are given repeatedly for 6 weeks cycles and are under $100 
They will break down all the steps needed to problem solve with model drawing from the simplest to fractions, ratios, percents, and more.

I took this course before I started teaching Singapore math and it really helped.